# How to configure Atom to run Dart in Dartium?

Tags: dart, atom-editor, dartium

How to set up the launch of web applications written in Dart, as it does WebStorm in Atom?

[image: Webstorm]

[image: Atom]

In the Atom, he tries to run itself Dart script rather than index.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Launch configurations stored in folder `.atom/launches`.

Eg. console (cli) configuration:

```
type: cli
path: test\test.dart

cli:
  args:
  cwd:
  checked: true
  debug: true
```

Launch of the web scripts (`type: web`) is not implemented yet.

[dartlang/lib/launch/launch_web.dart](https://github.com/dart-atom/dartlang/blob/6a8a5b22769b5aed7a7785962574708e3510ef4a/lib/launch/launch_web.dart#L17)
[lib/plugin.dart](https://github.com/dart-atom/dartlang/blob/bd956c04ac12b837047cc182e3e6d1b4f916df4c/lib/plugin.dart#L414)